# Jenkins: Can't connect to Docker daemon

Tags: jenkins, docker, centos

I am running Jenkins and Docker on a CentOS machine. I have a Jenkins job that pulls a Github repo and builds a Docker image. When I try running the job I get the error:

```
+ docker build -t myProject .
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

This problem occurs even though I have added jenkins to my docker usergroup via `sudo usermod -aG docker jenkins` and restarted my machine. How do I fix this?

By the way, if try changing the command to `sudo docker build -t myProject .` I just get the error `sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo`

Comment: What is 'sudo service docker status' returning on your Centos machine?

Comment: It is active: 

`sudo service docker status
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status  docker.service
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2016-06-29 14:10:13 UTC; 5h 40min ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
 Main PID: 24858 (docker)
   Memory: 30.1M`

Comment: Okay so as far as I understand: Jenkins isn't running inside docker?

Comment: No, I simply have a Jenkins job that has a shell script build step where it calls the `docker build -t myProject .` command. Docker is installed and running on the machine itself.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

After the installation of Jenkins and Docker.
Add jenkins user to dockergroup (like you did)

```
sudo gpasswd -a jenkins docker
```

Edit the following file

```
vi /usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service
```

And edit this rule to expose the API :

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker daemon -H unix:// -H tcp://localhost:2375
```

**Do not create a new line with** `ExecStart`, simply add the commands at the end of the existing line.

Now it's time to reload and restart your Docker daemon

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart docker
```

Then restart jenkins, you should be able to perform docker commands as jenkins user in your jenkins jobs

```
sudo service jenkins restart
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. Just curious, how does adding the TCP address to the ExecStart line impact Docker and the way it can talk with Jenkins?

Comment: So Jenkins can't call Docker directly, even though it's installed on the same machine?

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue with Jenkins.

I did fix it by adding **/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock** on docker-compose.yml :

```
  jenkins:
  container_name: jenkins
  build: "jenkins/"
  ports:
    - "8080:8080"
  environment:
    - JAVA_OPTS:-Djava.awt.headless=true
  volumes:
    - /var/jenkins_home
    - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks. I'm using Kubernetes pod temaplce, so needed to add: `hostPathVolume(mountPath: '/var/run/docker.sock', hostPath: '/var/run/docker.sock')`

Comment: @xbmono can you please share your template,as m doing the same it is not working for me

Comment: well I can't find that code as I changed this later on. So currently I have this template in jenkins shared lib: ```podTemplate(label: config.podLabel, namespace: 'default', name: 'jenkins-build', yaml: yamlConfigString,
            cloud: 'kubernetes',
            volumes: [
                    emptyDirVolume(mountPath: '/var/lib/docker', memory: false)
            ],
            imagePullSecrets: config.imagePullSecret,
            idleMinutes: config.podIdleTimeInMin
    )
            {
                body()
            }``` and the body is just standard kubernetes pod

Comment: hello, can you share the dockerFile file to build jenkins?

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to point your Jenkins docker host to 'unix:///var/run/docker.sock'

This is instead of running the actual docker host and opening it up.

Answer (score 3):

@lvthillo, your answer is good, but, not enough.  You also need to create the docker group.  See **Post Installation Steps for Docker**  **Manage Docker as a non-root user**
 https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/linux-postinstall/#manage-docker-as-a-non-root-user

to add the user running jenkins to the docker group.

E.g. if you run Jenkins server under the `jenkins` user:

Step 1: Create Docker Group

```
sudo groupadd docker
```

Step 2: Add your user to the `docker` group:

```
sudo usermod -aG docker jenkins
```

Step 3: Logout and log back in as jenkins, then test:

```
docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
```

The `docker` group is given special treatement by the docker daemon on startup just for this purpose.  Any user in that group can now call docker without sudo.  Use this with care.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/security/#docker-daemon-attack-surface

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `myProject` as a tag name.
the image name and tag must be all lowercase.

```
invalid argument "myProject" for "-t, --tag" flag: invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase
See 'docker build --help'.
```

if you are using docker-compose, you will see a misleading error

```
Couldn't connect to Docker daemon at http+docker://localunixsocket - is it running?

If it's at a non-standard location, specify the URL with the DOCKER_HOST environment variable.
```

https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/2816

Answer (score 0):

The fix for me was to...

Reload and restart the Docker daemon

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart docker
```

but then to

Disconnect the docker Jenkins agent though manage Jenkins -> manage nodes -> disconnect agent.

Then to re-connect the agent which will persist the user within the docker group.

Answer (score 0):

I was using jenkins-blueocean

My problem was the I wanted to use docker.sock and use the same daemon as the hosting system rather than deploying from a docker daemon setup by the container

for that make sure you have your DOCKER_HOST env properly set to the docker.socket you specify in a volume

```
--env DOCKER_HOST=unix:///var/run/docker.sock \
```

and specify the docker daemon to be the same one as the one hosting the container you want to defer to by specifying its docker.sock

```
--volume /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
```

Make sure you do not have any TLS args specified or it may try to use HTTPS to communicate.

REMOVE STUFF LIKE THIS:

```
--env DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1 \
```

DockerFile:

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:2.263.4-lts-jdk11
USER root
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y apt-transport-https \
       ca-certificates curl gnupg2 \
       software-properties-common
RUN curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/gpg | apt-key add -
RUN apt-key fingerprint 0EBFCD88
RUN add-apt-repository \
       "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian \
       $(lsb_release -cs) stable"
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y docker-ce-cli
USER jenkins
RUN jenkins-plugin-cli --plugins blueocean:1.24.4
```

run command:

```
docker run \
  --name jenkins-blueocean \
  --rm \
  --detach \
  --network jenkins \
  --env DOCKER_HOST=unix:///var/run/docker.sock \
  --env DOCKER_CERT_PATH=/certs/client \
  --publish 8080:8080 \
  --publish 50000:50000 \
  --volume jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home \
  --volume jenkins-docker-certs:/certs/client:ro \
  --volume /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
  myjenkins-blueocean:1.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to run:

`sudo gpasswd -a jenkins docker`

This will add Jenkins user to docker group.