# jenkins as docker container refused to connect to docker daemon in ubuntu

Tags: docker, ubuntu, jenkins

I'm running jenkins in docker container and docker daemon on same ubuntu machine, had a issue to connect to docker daemon.

[image: the error i got upon testing the connection]

check with netstat and telnet the connection is already running and connected.
[image: telnet connection also success connected]

i did refer to this and few more but still no luck, really need an advise on this.

https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/docker/
[Jenkins: Can't connect to Docker daemon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38105308/jenkins-cant-connect-to-docker-daemon)

Comment: Use jenkins-docker (the name of the jenkins container) as opposed to 127.0.0.1

Comment: i'm using jenkins/jenkins. is that really the issue? @RamanSailopal