# Jenkins: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon on Mac

Tags: docker, macos, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, devops

I'm running Jenkins for MacOS (using Homebrew) and Docker Desktop on Mac.

When I try to build docker image for Python app from Jenkins pipeline, the following error is reported:

```
+ docker build -t <docker image name>:41 .
ERROR: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

Jenkinsfile snippet:

```
pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
        ...
            stage("Build Docker Image") {
            agent {
                docker { image 'docker:24.0.5' }
            }
            environment {
        HOME = "${env.WORKSPACE}"
        }
            steps {
               script {
                dockerImage = docker.build("<docker image name>:${env.BUILD_ID}")
               }
            }
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

In previous stages, docker containers are successfully used.

I found similar case here [Jenkins: Can't connect to Docker daemon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38105308/jenkins-cant-connect-to-docker-daemon) for CentOS. I assume that I need to add my user to *docker* group (even if I can already run `docker` commands without `sudo`) but when I run `dscl . list /groups` command (the command which outputs all groups on Mac) I cannot find group named *docker*.
I have also tried to run the following in Jenkins pipeline:

```
+ whoami
whoami: unknown uid 501
```

Then I ran `id` command from my terminal to compare the *uid* and this is the *uid* of my user which I'm currently using and managing Jenkins.
Last, I created group *docker*:

```
sudo dseditgroup -o create docker
```

and added mentioned user to *docker* group:

```
sudo dseditgroup -o edit -a <user> -t user docker
```

and restared Docker Desktop and Jenkins. The issue persists.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue by changing "agent" to "any" in the Jenkins pipeline stage:

```
pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
        ...
            stage("Build Docker Image") {
            agent any
            environment {
        HOME = "${env.WORKSPACE}"
        }
            steps {
               script {
                dockerImage = docker.build("<docker image name>:${env.BUILD_ID}")
               }
            }
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

`docker:24.0.5` docker image was not working due to docker-in-docker scenario. Now, the docker image is successfully built on my local docker engine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).